# Why does ROS_INFO_STREAM print two time stamps?

Tags: ros, timestamp, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use ROS_INFO_STREAM, it prints two timestamps:

```
[ INFO] [1348651448.232151821, 1323877497.479939999]: Hello World!
```

What do they represent? I looked at the [rosconsole docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole), but I can't find an explanation.

I noticed this behaviour while running a bag with `use_sim_time = true` and `--clock` (if that makes any difference)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44591/why-does-ros_info_stream-print-two-time-stamps?/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first time looks like your current local time while the second on looks like the time recorded within the bag-file

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2